# Dolby C recording on CD remastering

Tags: adobe-audition, tape, dolby, cd, remastering

I have a CD from the 90s which has a professionally recorded "Dolby C" recording of a classical singing recital.

I would like to remaster this, so that as much of the original quality is retained. I also have some Dolby C and Dolby B tapes of the same recording. Played on my tape machine, the Dolby B tapes sound much better but this might be due to the machine. I can easily export the CD to a WAV file and I have experience doing simple remastering using Adobe Audition.

What do you suggest?
Any advice, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, Dolby C and Dolby B were consumer cassette tape noise reduction techniques used in the 80's. For you to have a CD with dolby C encoded audio this would have to have been transferred clean (without decoding) from a pre-recorded cassette. In order to decode this you would need a Dolby C decoder.

You might be able to use something like : https://anaxwaves.github.io/DDiCodec/index.html
to do it, however you would have to rip the WAV audio from the CD and then pass it through this decoder.

Comment: Ah okay, this is really helpful, thank you.